# Scala - weird behaviour with Iterator.toList

Tags: scala, iterator

I am new to Scala and I have a function as follows:

```
def selectSame(messages: BufferedIterator[Int]) = {
  val head = messages.head
  messages.takeWhile(_ == head)
}
```

Which is selecting from a buffered iterator only the elems matching the head. I am subsequently using this code:

```
val messageStream = List(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
if (!messageStream.isEmpty) {
  var lastTimeStamp = messageStream.head.timestamp
  while (!messageStream.isEmpty) {
    val messages = selectSame(messageStream).toList
    println(messages)
}
```

Upon first execution I am getting (1,1,1) as expected, but then I only get the List(2), like if I lost one element down the line... Probably I am doing sth wrong with the iterators/lists, but I am a bit lost here.

Comment: sorry, I meant List.iterator.buffered. Apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scaladoc of `Iterator` says about `takeWhile`:

> Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it
>   was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the
>   old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in
>   changes to the new iterator as well.

So that's why. This basically means you cannot directly do what you want with `Iterators` and `takeWhile`. IMHO, easiest would be to quickly write your own recursive function to do that.

If you want to stick with `Iterators`, you could use the `sameElements` method on the `Iterator` to generate a duplicate where you'd call `dropWhile`.

Even better: Use `span` repeatedly:

```
def selectSame(messages: BufferedIterator[Int]) = {
  val head = messages.head
  messages.span(_ == head)
}

def iter(msgStream: BufferedIterator[Int]): Unit = if (!msgStream.isEmpty) {
  val (msgs, rest) = selectSame(msgStream)
  println(msgs.toList)
  iter(rest)
}

val messageStream = List(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
if (!messageStream.isEmpty) {
  var lastTimeStamp = messageStream.head.timestamp
  iter(messageStream0
}
```

Comment: +1: The first `2` element must be consumed in order to test whether it's still equal to `1`.  So, as the docs warn, the iterator's state is not as was expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. ANy idea to achieve the same functionality i.e. selecting first N same objects from iterator in a functional way?